Can I leave the M25 at Clacket Lane Services?
I am planning a drive from north-west of London to Kent. Bing Maps recommends leaving the M25 motorway at Clacket Lane Services (avoiding road works in Oxted). The company web site does not mention that route, although other maps (e.g. https://www.roads.org.uk/motorway/m25/80) show it.
Many UK service stations are built by other roads, and access is restricted, so the public cannot enter or leave the motorway using the other road.
Is it allowed to drive from the M25 on to Clacket Lane? I am heading eastbound, but the same applies to the westbound direction.

Given that street view images show 'do not enter' signs, a barricade, and signs warning of 24/7 CCTV monitoring for illegal access, my guess (as a non-local) is that driving from the service plaza onto Clacket Lane is not possible when the gate is closed, and highly inadvisable when the gate is open.

I'm not sure where from/to you are going, but the road closure in Oxted is very unlikely to affect you, it's on a small street parallel to the A25, and should only be a concern for people actually going to that stretch of road.

@jcaron, thanks. It seems it will work to leave M25 at junction 6, on the way to Hever Castle.

Google Street View shows that, eastbound, a road linking the service area to Clacket Lane exists, but has no entry signs (with exceptions for authorised vehicles and guests staying at the service station hotel) as well as a barrier across the road.
https://maps.app.goo.gl/c8RKPVreWDEHBidPA?g_st=ac
Westbound looks similar.
Unfortunately this means that legally you can't use this road, and if the barrier is closed, you physically might not be able to either.

That's what I feared. Actually, I live in a Google-free environment (as far as possible) so don't use street view.
